# how to add class camelCased to body

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layout-update

I was trying to **add a camelCased class into the body tag**, is there some way to do it? I'm using this:

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="addBodyClass"><classname>camelCasedClass</classname></action>
</reference>
```

But it outputs:

```
<body class="catalog-category-view camelcasedclass">
```

Obviously i could change the class name, but it come from a third party lib and I don't wanna change it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `addBodyClass` method automatically lower case the class:

```
public function addBodyClass($className)
{
    $className = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]+#', '-', strtolower($className));
    $this->setBodyClass($this->getBodyClass() . ' ' . $className);
    return $this;
}
```

To avoid that I reckon you should try to set the class directly:

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="setBodyClass"><classname>camelCasedClass</classname></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: That explains "everything", about to do it in the code, I can't, we add that class in the admin section only.

Comment: @Di36o I don't totally understand your comment. Do you need further help ?

Comment: No, your answer explains what I was asking for, but i can't "vote up" your answer :(

Comment: @Di36o no worries mark it as accepted when you can, not a big deal ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this for admin, locate file

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\local.xml
```

and add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
          <action method="setBodyClass"><classname>camelCased</classname></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: It won't work, my goal was add a camel cased class into frontend category  page, using the "Custom layout update" field in the admin section.